# CKEditor: IE Edge carriage return issue

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal-7, ckeditor

Using CKEditor module versions 7.x-1.17 & 7.x-1.16 on multiple Drupal 7.x sites, pressing the return key at the end of a line in IE Edge returns the cursor to the beginning of the line instead of creating a carriage return.

Any suggestions?